# MAVEN Plugin generating ibm-web-bnd.xml in wrong place with RAD 8

Tags: maven, m2e, ibm-rad

I've a project that has been converted from an ANT build to eclipse we are using IBM RAD8 and the m2e maven plugin.

The connection between the web.xml and the ibm-web-bnd.xml binding files does not seem to be working. The binding file has a number of resource mapping binding problems and when i generate the ibm-web-bnd.xml (by using the web.xml designer).

Also when it is generated it lands under **target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xml** How Do I control where it lands? its not where I expect it?

Comment: By which plugin is the mentioned file being generated?